# MPAndroidChart Error "method does not override from its superclass" when using getXOffset and getYOffset

Tags: android

Im working using the MPAndroid Chart, and this is my first app on AndroidStudio and Im Electronics Engineer

I did my code according to this link: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView

and I got an error : error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

I dont know why can't be override

I tried everything , searched the web, but I can't find any solution for this

This is MyMarker.java class

```
package com.example.programsql;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.MarkerView;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MyMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    private TextView tvContent;
    private long referenceTimestamp;  // minimum timestamp in your data set
    private DateFormat mDataFormat;
    private Date mDate;

    public MyMarkerView (Context context, int layoutResource, long referenceTimestamp) {
        super(context, layoutResource);
        // this markerview only displays a textview
        tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        this.referenceTimestamp = referenceTimestamp;
        this.mDataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        this.mDate = new Date();

    }

    // callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
    // content (user-interface)
    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        long currentTimestamp = (int)e.getX() + referenceTimestamp;

        tvContent.setText(e.getY() + " en  " + getTimedate(currentTimestamp)); // set the entry-value as the display text

    }


    @Override <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I get error on this
    public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
        // this will center the marker-view horizontally
        return -(getWidth() / 2);
    }

    @Override <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I get error on this too
    public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
        // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
        return -getHeight();
    }

    private String getTimedate(long timestamp){

        try{
            mDate.setTime(timestamp*1000); 
            return mDataFormat.format(mDate); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            return "xx";
        }
    }
}
```

This occurs on the last both @override part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On newest version (*3.1.0*), 2 methods `getXOffset()` and `getYOffset()` has been replaced by `getOffset()`. So change your code from

```
@Override
public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
    // this will center the marker-view horizontally
    return -(getWidth() / 2);
}

@Override
public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
    // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
    return -getHeight();
}
```

to

```
@Override
public MPPointF getOffset() {
    return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked... but in the leftmost data value, the X position of the first marker appears to the right of the data point, but Y position of the first marker is ok. The other right ones are all ok.... Another thing, the markers in the left and right appears outside the graph, I found some code, but maybe these are deprecated because uses deprecated code, can you help me with that? Thank you...

Comment: @Mangostain I'm having the exact same issue with the first item not being centered. Did you ever figure out a solution?